# Is it possible for part-for-part metonymy to exist?

Tags: lexical-relations

In linguistics, I have seen prior examples of part-for-whole (`The new face in the class`, where `face` refers to the individual person) and whole-for-part (`New York won the game`, where `New York` refers to the New York Yankees for example) metonymy. But is it possible for part-for-part metonymy to exist?

Comment: How would you separate part-for-part from part-for-whole_part (face -> head -> person)?

Comment: Ideally by supplying some context to it, but apart from that, it doesn't seem plausible.

Comment: How would that be different from any other kind of metaphor? When I refer to the _foot_ of a mountain, I _could_ say, well, that is using the foot-part-of-a-human to represent the bottom-part-of-the-mountain, but we wouldn't normally call that metonymy.

Comment: If _The Yankees beat the Giants_ means the same thing as _New York beat San Francisco_ (and they're logically synonymous -- if one is true so is the other, and if one is false so is the other), then what brand of metonymy do we have?

Comment: @jlawler I don't think you're approaching this correctly. Yankees for New York, and Giants for San Francisco are two separate metonymys by themselves. I don't think you can combine two to get one.

Comment: This inherently impossible due to the fact that in metonimies something stands for something else. How can two subsets stand for each other?

Comment: @aml Thanks for your help, this is clear to me now. Would you mind writing this as an answer, so that others can quickly look this up as well?